# Returning struct of struct by a C function

Tags: c

I tried to create a simple `split` function to return elements as a struct, and used another struct to return the results and the number of elements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct TOKENS
{
  int length;
  char word[];
};

struct OUTPUT
{
  struct TOKENS *a;
  int l;
};

struct OUTPUT explode(char *a, char *b)
{
  struct TOKENS tokens[10];
  int i = 0;
  char *ptr = strtok(a, b);
  while (ptr != NULL)
  {
    tokens[i].length = strlen(ptr);
    strcpy(tokens[i].word, ptr);
    ptr = strtok(NULL, b);
    i++;
  }
  struct OUTPUT r = {
      .a = &tokens[0], .l = i};
  return r;
}

int main()
{
  char str[] = "This is test for the start";
  struct OUTPUT r = explode(str, " ");
  struct TOKENS *tokens = r.a;
  printf("%d\n", r.l);
  for (int i = 0; i < r.l; i++)
  {
    printf("%d %s (%d)\n", i, tokens[i].word, tokens[i].length);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

However, the output is not what I aimed for:

```
6
0  (4)
1  (2)
2  (4)
3  (3)
4  (3)
5 start (5)
```

Comment: The `word` field of `struct TOKENS` is defined as a *flexible array member*, that requires a special care to allocate. But you don't do it.

Comment: No sure what output you're aiming for, but the the word[] structure element is a problem.

Comment: One of the consequences of what @EugeneSh. mentioned is that you can't make an array of them. So `struct TOKENS tokens[10];` is flat out. You can use an array of pointers to them using the special care that Eugene mentions.

Comment: You also cannot rely on returning a struct with a flexible array member by value, or at least on the FAM being preserved through that process.

Comment: You can't put `&tokens[0]` in a structure that you're returning. `tokens` is a local variable, it's destroyed when the function returns, so any pointers to it become invalid.

Comment: You are overthinking this. The `explode` function should take four parameters: `a`, `b`, a token array, and the length of the token array. The function should return the number of tokens found. So the function signature is `int explode(char *a, char *b, char *tokens[], int maxt);` Then, the calling code in `main` looks like this `char *token[10]; int count = explode(str, " ", token, 10); for (int i=0; i<count; i++) printf("%s\n", token[i]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FAM's may be useful in some instances, but the old reliable `malloc()` (and its user `strdup()`, if available) can be used here.

`realloc()` is used to start and to grow array of ptrs to individual 'token' structs

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // for `exit()`
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int length;
    char *word; // NB: pointer, not FAM
} TOKENS_t;

typedef struct {
    TOKENS_t *a;
    int l;
} OUTPUT_t;

#define USE_SRC_STR
// or not defined in order to use dynamic allocation of "word" copies

// return ptr to struct instead of entire struct
OUTPUT_t *explode( char *a, char *b ) {
    OUTPUT_t *r = calloc( 1, sizeof *r ); // initially all bytes = 0
    // test for NULL return omitted for brevity

    // only one invocation of strtok()
    for( char *ptr = a; (ptr = strtok( ptr, b )) != NULL; ptr = NULL ) {

        // cautiously growing array of pointers
        TOKENS_t *tmp = realloc( r->a, (r->l + 1) * sizeof *tmp );
        if( tmp == NULL ) {
            fprintf( stderr, "realloc failed on %d\n", r->l + 1 );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
        // preserve "word"
#ifdef USE_SRC_STR
        tmp[ r->l ].word = ptr;
#else
        tmp[ r->l ].word = strdup( ptr );
#endif
        tmp[ r->l ].length = strlen( ptr ); // preserve length of "word"
        r->a = tmp; // realloc() may have relocated extended array
        r->l++; // got one more
    }

    return r;
}

int main() {
    char str[] = "This is test for the start";

    OUTPUT_t *r = explode( str, " " ); // capture returned pointer

    printf( "%d\n", r->l );
    for( int i = 0; i < r->l; i++ )
        printf( "%d: %s (%d)\n", i, r->a[i].word, r->a[i].length );

#ifndef USE_SRC_STR
    // free those buffers containing copies of "word"s
    while( (r->l)-- )
        free( r->a[ r->l ].word );
#endif

    free( r ); // free this, too!

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
6
0: This (4)
1: is (2)
2: test (4)
3: for (3)
4: the (3)
5: start (5)
```

Or, below is another alternative where the caller passes the address of a 'top level' struct to the function (that now just does its job and returns nothing.)

```
void explode( OUTPUT_t *r, char *a, char *b ) {
    for( char *ptr = a; (ptr = strtok( ptr, b )) != NULL; ptr = NULL ) {
        TOKENS_t *tmp = (TOKENS_t *)realloc( r->a, (r->l + 1) * sizeof *tmp );
        if( tmp == NULL ) {
            fprintf( stderr, "realloc failed on %d\n", r->l + 1 );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
        tmp[ r->l ].word = ptr; // using original string
        tmp[ r->l ].length = strlen( ptr );
        r->a = tmp;
        r->l++;
    }
}

int main() {
    char str[] = "This is test for the start";

    OUTPUT_t r = { 0 }; // define initialised top level instance
    explode( &r, str, " " ); // pass into "helper" function

    printf( "%d\n", r.l );
    for( int i = 0; i < r.l; i++ )
        printf( "%d: %s (%d)\n", i, r.a[i].word, r.a[i].length );

    free( r.a ); // don't forget to "clean up"

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer with very informative explanations. Thanks. What is the purpose of `USE_SRC_STR`? What is the implication of assigning `ptr` directly or a copy via `strdup`? I mean, how should I judge which approach better serves the purpose?

Comment: @Googlebot The `#define` is to include the two versions in the same code example. You can remove whichever version does not suit. The `ptr` v. `strdup` depends on the lifespan of the string that is being chopped-up into "words". If you want to keep/use the words after the original string "goes out of scope", you need to make copies. Or, maybe the string hangs around while you deal with each word, so all you want is pointers into that string without asking for slivers of "heap" to make a copy of each word (ie: "faster"). Depends on usage after "explosions" `:-)`

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, you have to use dynamic allocation when using a structure with a flexible array member. The size of the structure doesn't include the array size, you have to add the size of the array when calling `malloc()`.

This means you can't have an array of `TOKENS`, so you need `OUTPUT.a` to be an array of pointers. Use `malloc()` and `realloc()` to allocate the memory for `r.a`, and use `malloc()` to allocate the memory for each `TOKENS` element.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct TOKENS
{
    int length;
    char word[];
};

struct OUTPUT
{
    struct TOKENS **a;
    int l;
};

struct OUTPUT explode(char *a, char *b)
{
    struct OUTPUT r = {.a = NULL, .l = 0};
    int i = 0;
    char *ptr = strtok(a, b);
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        r.l++;
        r.a = realloc(r.a, r.l * sizeof(*r.a));
        struct TOKENS *token = malloc(sizeof(*token)  + strlen(ptr) + 1);
        token->length = strlen(ptr);
        strcpy(token->word, ptr);
        r.a[i] = token;
        ptr = strtok(NULL, b);
        i++;
    }
    return r;
}

int main()
{
    char str[] = "This is test for the start";
    struct OUTPUT r = explode(str, " ");
    struct TOKENS **tokens = r.a;
    printf("%d\n", r.l);
    for (int i = 0; i < r.l; i++)
    {
        printf("%d %s (%d)\n", i, tokens[i]->word, tokens[i]->length);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < r.l; i++) {
        free(tokens[i]);
    }
    free(tokens);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not only do the characteristics you describe mean that one can't have an array of structures with FAMs, but more directly, the C language specification explicitly expresses that restriction as a language constraint (C17 6.7.2.1/3).